# Regex to remove only white spaces from left and right side of array and object brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove white spaces from left and right side of array and objects.
for example:

```
[ **remove space**{**remove space** "test t":"asd asd" **remove space**} **remove space**]
```

Comment: so, you're obviously working with string representation of an object? if this string representation is **valid** JSON (the example is), you could simply `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(your_string));`

Comment: Agreed with @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression literal.

```js
str = '[      {      "test t":"asd asd"      }      ]';
str = str.replace( / *([\[|\]|\{|\}]) */g, "$1");
console.log( str );
```